# how i add ctp extension in netbeans

Tags: php, cakephp, netbeans, netbeans6.8

How i add CTP Extension using following method but it is not worked can any one help me ?

1. Open preferences.
2. Select Miscellaneous tab.
3. Select Files sub-tab thing.
4. Click on New file extension and enter tpl.
5. Select the mime type.
6. Click ok. Done!

Comment: In step 4, you write "Click on New file extension and enter **tpl**." Did you enter "tpl" or "ctp"? I downloaded and installed Netbeans, followed the instructions you posted (with the 'ctp' extension), and it worked great.

Answer (score 34):

**Go to :**
Tools -> Options -> Miscellaneous -> Files

**Then :**
Click on "New" -> Type in ctp -> Click "OK"

Associate with PHP text/x-php5

*And you are finished.*

Comment: I guess you need to set "Associated File Type (MIME)" = "PHP Files (text/x-php5)"

Comment: No, you are **not** "*finished*." As of Netbeans 8.2, you *still* can not create a new file with the "ctp" extension. You can create a new file with any other extension, but it will not allow you to rename the file to a "ctp" extension. You basically need to create the file, then rename it from the OS.

Answer (score 7):

To add the ctp extension in netbeans

- Go to Tools -> Options -> Miscellaneous -> Files
- then click on "New" -> Type in ctp -> Click "OK"
- After "Associated File Type (MIME)" -> select (text/x-php5) -> Click "OK"

Comment: Same comment as above for @user442616. Netbeans will recognize the "ctp" file and syntax color it like a "PHP" file, but it still won't let you create a new file with a "ctp" extension from within the IDE.

Answer (score 3):

You could install plugin [PHP CakePHP Framework](http://plugins.netbeans.org/plugin/44579/php-cakephp-framework) and enable it for desired projects.

Comment: OK, not surprisingly, this answer actually **works.** Up-vote.

Answer (score 0):

Create an empty file and then put your desired extension.

Comment: This doesnt work as Netbeans automatically creates the extension for you when you choose the file type

Comment: Create an empty file with the desired extension in the desired directory/folder from the OS. Netbeans will not create the file for you, but it doesn't complain when it's there already.