# Syntax highlighting for .ctp files with Netbeans+ Cakephp in Mac OS

Tags: macos, cakephp, netbeans, syntax, ctp

I code Cakephp with Netbeans in Mac Os. My syntaxs in .ctp file doesn't highlighted(colored). I found the answer but only for Windows :( . How can I do for Mac? Tks!

Comment: Why should the procedure be any different on OSX? **http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2711366/how-i-add-ctp-extension-in-netbeans** | **http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E50453_01/doc.80/e50452/working_nbeans.htm#NBDAG2075** (< that's what you find when you use the NetBeans help)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Windows: Tools -> Options -> Miscellaneous -> Files -> File Extensions -> New -> Type 'ctp' -> OK

MacOS: Netbeans -> Preferences -> Miscellaneous -> Files -> File Extensions -> New -> Type 'ctp' -> OK

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

Firstly you'll want to install the CakePHP plugin for Netbeans.

http://plugins.netbeans.org/plugin/44579/php-cakephp-framework

Then you're done.

Answer (score 0):

Go to Tools > Options > Miscellaneous > Files

1. Select File Extension = 'ctp' - (create one from the new button if the extension doesn't exist in the drop down list already)
2. Select Associated File Type (MIME) = PHP files

Hope that it will work for you.